# Calling Python from Objective-C

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing a Python/ObjC application and I need to call some methods in my Python classes from ObjC.
I've tried several stuffs with no success.

- How can I call a Python method from Objective-C?
- My Python classes are being instantiated in Interface Builder. How can I call a method from that instance?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use PyObjC.

It is included with Leopard & later.

```
>>> from Foundation import *
>>> a = NSArray.arrayWithObjects_("a", "b", "c", None)
>>> a
(
      a,
      b,
      c
)
>>> a[1]
'b'
>>> a.objectAtIndex_(1)
'b'
>>> type(a)
<objective-c class NSCFArray at 0x7fff708bc178>
```

It even works with iPython:

```
In [1]: from Foundation import *

In [2]: a = NSBundle.allFrameworks()

In [3]: ?a
Type:       NSCFArray
Base Class: <objective-c class NSCFArray at 0x1002adf40>
```

`

To call from Objective-C into Python, the easiest way is to:

- declare an abstract superclass in Objective-C that contains the API you want to call
- create stub implementations of the methods in the class's @implementation
- subclass the class in Python and provide concrete implementations
- create a factory method on the abstract superclass that creates concrete subclass instances

I.e.

```
@interface Abstract : NSObject
- (unsigned int) foo: (NSString *) aBar;
+ newConcrete;
@end

@implementation Abstract
- (unsigned int) foo: (NSString *) aBar { return 42; }
+ newConcrete { return [[NSClassFromString(@"MyConcrete") new] autorelease]; }
@end

.....

class Concrete(Abstract):
    def foo_(self, s): return s.length()

.....

x = [Abstract newFoo];
[x  foo: @"bar"];
```

Comment: I do not see how this works.  For example, I'm assuming the following:
 (1) put the python code in a file Concrete.py  
 (2) put the obj-c code in Abstract.h/m  
Given that, how exactly do you build this program?

Comment: Update: There is clarification on this ticket: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772491/call-from-objective-c-into-python)

Comment: Is this missing a closing parenthesis after "MyConcrete"?