# How do you call PyObjC code from Objective-C?

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling Python from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308079/calling-python-from-objective-c)

I'm a long-time Python programmer and short-time Cocoa programmer. I'm just getting started with PyObjC and it's really amazing how easy it it is to get stuff done. That said, I wanted to try using pure ObjC for my controller with PyObjC models. I might be enjoy letting Python be Python and Objective-C be Objective-C. I figured it was worth a try, anyways.

*Except* I can't figure out or find anything about how to call Python from Objective-C, only the other way around. Can someone point me to any resources on this? (Maybe it's on the PyObjC site but I just don't know what I'm looking for?)

Edit: I'm most interested, at the basic level, in being able to call a Python module and get some native ObjC data types back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, guess I should've searched a bit more:

[Calling Python from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308079/calling-python-from-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible approaches. The most tempting is to use py2app to compile a loadable bundle from your python code from which you can access the principal class using `NSBundle`. Unfortunately, this use case hasn't gotten much love from the py2app developers, and I've found several bugs in 10.5 and 10.6, including a rather nasty memory leak when passing data from python back in to Objective-C. I wouldn't recommend using py2app at thist point.

The second approach is invert the embedding. Write a Python cocoa app and load your Objective-C code from a bundle at startup (even in main()). If you already have a large Objective-C app, this may take a bit of work. The only downside, that I'm ware of, is that you won't be able to use GC in your Objective-C code, but this is really a universal limitation in working with PyObjC.

Finally, you can instantiate a python interpreter in your Objective-C code to load your python code. This is obviously more involved, but may the best option if you already have a large Objective-C codebase into which you want to inject your python code. The main.m file from the Python-Cococa application template in Xcode is a good place to start to see this in action.